# how can i convert it into string. when execute this statement type error occur

Tags: python, sql, types, printing, casting

```
print("Average minimum temperature in Fahrenheit : {0: .2f}".format(data['Min_Temperature_F'].mean()))
```

[This error is occur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/90Zpi.png)

Comment: Please post the full traceback of the error.

Comment: Is `data` a pandas dataframe?

Comment: the column `data['Min_Temperature_F']` might not be float, so try `.format(data['Min_Temperature_F'].astype('float').mean())`

Comment: yes data is pandas dataframe